# Pivot Table from VBA macro displaying incorrect data

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

Somehow my Pivot Table created from my VBA script displays different data than when i create the pivot table manually.

My macro does the following:

- Database is in sheet 2. Pivot is in sheet 1.
- Macro deletes all rows in sheet 2 and adds new data.
- M deletes rows containing the current pivot.
- M deletes the data-connection for the pivot.
- M creates new data-connection for the new data in sheet 2 and creates a new 
  pivot in sheet 1.

Everything works without errors, but somehow the data is not the same as to when i create the pivot manually.

My guess is that it uses some old data-connection, but im not sure how or how to fix this.

VBA - Code for pivot table creation:

```
'Delete old pivot
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A1:C5").Select
Selection.ClearContents

'Create new Connection
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("PivotConnection").Delete
Workbooks("File.xlsm").Connections.Add2 _
    "PivotConnection", "", _
    "WORKSHEET;*ABSOLUTE PATH*[File.xlsm]Sheet2" _
    , "Sheet2!$A:$Q", 7, True, False

'Create new pivot
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:= _
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("PivotConnection"), Version:=6).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1), TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion:=6

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3")
    .ColumnGrand = True
    .HasAutoFormat = True
    .DisplayErrorString = False
    .DisplayNullString = True
    .EnableDrilldown = True
    .ErrorString = ""
    .MergeLabels = False
    .NullString = ""
    .PageFieldOrder = 2
    .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RowGrand = True
    .PrintTitles = False
    .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
    .TotalsAnnotation = True
    .CompactRowIndent = 1
    .VisualTotals = False
    .InGridDropZones = False
    .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
    .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = True
    .DisplayContextTooltips = True
    .ShowDrillIndicators = True
    .PrintDrillIndicators = False
    .DisplayEmptyRow = False
    .DisplayEmptyColumn = False
    .AllowMultipleFilters = False
    .SortUsingCustomLists = True
    .DisplayImmediateItems = True
    .ViewCalculatedMembers = True
    .FieldListSortAscending = False
    .ShowValuesRow = False
    .CalculatedMembersInFilters = True
    .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotCache.RefreshOnFileOpen = False
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Just to clarify how the data is incorrect:

- The distinct count of a row gives me e.g. 1000
- I run the macro and new pivot with modified data is created
- Distinct count still shows 1000
- Manually created pivot shows e.g. 980 for distinct count

Comment: How does it differ? Suggest you upload a photo.

Comment: For example if i use "distinct count" it is a different value than in my manually created table. It seems that the database ist not updating correctly.